# Proportionally scale a div with CSS based on max-width (similar to img scaling)

Tags: image, html, css, scale

Is it possible to proportionally scale a `div` like an `img` using only CSS?  Here is my first attempt: http://dabblet.com/gist/1783363

## Example

```
div {
 max-width:100px;
 max-height:50px;
}
img {
 max-width:100px;
 max-height:50px;
}
```

### Actual Result

```
Container: 200 x 100
Div:       100 x 50
Image:     100 x 50

Container: 50  x 100
Div:       50  x 50  // I want this to be 50x25, like the image
Image:     50  x 25
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: The Dabblet servers are currently down, so this could be not what you are after at all, but isn't that what percentages are for?

Comment: @bfrohs: note that the backticks don't work in titles. :)

Comment: @sarnold - Thanks for the rewrite.  Much clearer.

Comment: @bfrohs did all the work: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9219005/revisions I just removed a few backticks from the title. (I should have also fixed the spelling error in the title but I didn't see it until now.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since vertical paddings set in percent are calculated out of *width* of an element we can make a div always be of a certain aspect ratio.

If we set `padding-top:50%; height:0`, the height of the div will always be half of its width. 
And to make text appear inside such a container you need to make it `position:relative` and put another div inside it and position it absolutely 10px away from all four sides (the padding you set first).

See [my fork of your code](http://dabblet.com/gist/1794086).

Comment: genius! [filling character limit]

Comment: If this doesn't work for anyone (it didn't for me), use padding-bottom instead of padding-top, as per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894506/can-i-scale-a-div-height-proportionally-to-width-of-the-div-with-the-help-of-onl

Comment: Unfortunately horizontal padding *also* uses the width, so this trick doesn't work with a percent height and padding-left.

Answer (score 5):

Sort of. You could use transformations to scale it up, but I'm not sure that's what you have in mind.

`-webkit-transform:scale(2);` (and other prefixes) would double it in size, without altering page layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.container img {
    height:50vw;
}
```

The vw follows the viewport
You need to set in the head of your document:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
```