# Scaling div elements if they're in a row?

Tags: css, html, scale

I have been mulling over this SO post regarding how to implement scaling divs (for iPad viewers, etc)--see the fork with 12 votes:

[Proportionally scale a div with CSS based on max-width (similar to img scaling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219005/proportionally-scale-a-div-with-css-based-on-max-width-similar-to-img-scaling)

The issue is that my current layout is using two float:left div IDs to make a row-like config for my divs. See here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33061840/site/Pokesite.html

& my code:

http://pastebin.com/fspfRUD2

My question is, do I need to redo my divs so that they're positioned as *Spader Shut*'s fork is? Or can I keep my current layout and still have my divs proportionally scale to window size?

What I ultimately want to achieve is for all my content to scale to window height, proportionally: so that iPad viewers, etc are still able to view the website.

Comment: Have you looked into *responsive design*?

Comment: google @media queries or responsive design...or better yet...give twitter bootstrap a try, it handles all this for you......

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using responsive tables: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/