# Proportional scaling -- need help understanding how this css code works

Tags: css

I created this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/HfpHf/1/) based on the following stackoverflow question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9236397

The relevant bits are:

```
.box-parent {
width:95%;
padding-bottom:95%;
height:0;
position:relative;

}

.box {
border-radius: 10%;
width:100%; 
height:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0;
background-color:rgb(17, 17, 17);
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;

}
```

The trouble is I don't really understand how or why it works. More specifically, what does setting height: 0 on the parent do and why does setting padding-bottom to the same percentage as width result in the child being a square?

Comment: That's some weird `CSS` does it do anything special for you or do you just wan't some square boxes?

Comment: heh. I want square boxes that shrink and enlarge auto-magically based on the screen size. Only way I could find to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `li` element doesn't have got specified `height`. So child elements have to be determinated only by its width.

We can't use `height: 100%` to specify `parent-box` because we don't know the height of `li`.
The only solution is use `padding` which is destined only by parent element's width as you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp) in percentage specifition. There is written *Specifies the padding in percent of the width of the containing element*.

Comment: I realize we don't know the height of the li. I'm just wondering what setting the box-parent to 0 accomplishes and also why/how setting the parent padding to the parent width result in a box?

Comment: Here is setting height to 0 unnecessary. It is necessary if you want the parent-box to contain for exmaple same text.  The padding result in box, because padding is calculated from parent width, so width: 95% is the same as padding-bottom: 95%. It is the same size.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Why would it be necessary if I had text in there?

Comment: It could be necessary if you add some text to parent-box after the div box. Otherwise it can break the box. As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HfpHf/2/).